# Trying to create an alias to include options in powershell

Tags: powershell, alias

My goal is to have an alias to run a command with -o at the end.

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> vlab -o  <various different arguments>
```

I have tried to setup an alias, but Set-Alias recognizes -o as a parameter Option, and
placing it in single or double quotes fails

```
> set-alias vlab 'vlab -o'
> vlab
vlab : The term 'vlab -o' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

also setup a profile.ps1 with a function, but this just hangs when I run it.

```
Function VlabSpeed {
     vlab -o
}
Set-Alias vlab VlabSpeed
```

Is it possible to set an alias like this?

Comment: on your `VlabSpeed` function, try with `vlab -o @args` in it's body

Comment: vlab -o @args   still hangs the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap:

- **PowerShell aliases can only map a name to another command *name* or executable *file path*** - unlike in, say, Bash, **defining *arguments* as part of the mapping is *not* supported**.

**To incorporate arguments, you indeed need a *function*** rather than an alias:

- **Inside that function, you can use `@args` to pass any arguments through to another command**, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out.
- There is no need for *both* an alias and a function - just name your function *directly* as the short name you desire.

**If your short (function) name is the same as the file name of the external program that it wraps, you need to *disambiguate*** the two to avoid *infinite recursion*:

- On Windows:

  - Use the external program's *filename extension*, typically `.exe`:

    ```
    function vlab { vlab.exe -o @args }
    ```
- On Unix-like platforms:

  - Given that executables there (typically) have *no* filename extension, use the *full path* to disambiguate:

    ```
    function vlab { /path/to/vlab -o @args }
    ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.. using vlab.exe to distinguish them allowed it to work properly..  I used the function you created, it works properly now.
It sounds like I was hitting a recursion as I named them the same, which caused it to  "hang"

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @bandion - indeed, infinite recursion was the problem.