# How to add a Powershell alias for kubectl command?

Tags: powershell, alias, kubectl, powershell-5.1

In Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10 I am trying to add an alias by calling:

```
New-Alias -Name k -Value "kubectl -n my-aks-namespace"
```

However when I try to use it by calling `k get pods` it seems to me, that all the 3 words in the value of my alias are interpreted *as a single string* and as such the command `"kubectl -n my-aks-namespace" get pods` is of course not found by Powershell, resulting in the error:

```
k : The term 'kubectl -n my-aks-namespace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ k get pods
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (kubectl -n my-aks-namespace:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I just call `kubectl -n my-aks-namespace get pods` without trying to use the alias, everything works and the list of pods is printed.

**UPDATE:**

Many thanks for your comments, I have run `notepad $PROFILE` and put the following line in there:

```
function k { kubectl -n my-aks-namespace @args }
```

And now I am able to call the commands like:

```
k get nodes
k get pods
```

at my Powershell prompt. (For this to work, I had to remove my broken `New-Alias` first.)

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998408/trying-to-create-an-alias-to-include-options-in-powershell - summary is you can’t specify parameters in an alias - you need to wrap it in a function instead. The error you’re seeing is because the command you’ve aliased is treating the args as part of the command *name*

Comment: In short: `function k { kubectl -n my-aks-namespace @args }`