Git Alias for Powershell Profile Does Not Work
Git commands work on my Powershell and I've verified that my environment variables on Path for Git are correct. My profile looks like this:
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/json.omp.json' | Invoke-Expression
fnm env --use-on-cd | Out-String | Invoke-Expression # for Node and NPM
Set-Alias gst 'git status'

And the error I get is the following:
> gst
gst : The term 'git status' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gst
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git status:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Aliases are only for the command name, not for passing arguments (e.g. the status argument in your git status) into the command. If you want to hard-code arguments you need to wrap it in a function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000204/3156906 for more details
